# Turn off push notifications in my app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Successfully implemented Firebase in my app for sending push notifications about my blog, but now I want to know how a user can "turn off" the notifications that I send to the app, here is my code:

```
package com.lfcchile;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

/**
 * Created by Jona on 7/23/16.
 */
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_destacado)
                .setContentTitle("LFC Chile")
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                .setTicker("Ticker")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());

    }

}
```

Ideas please? thanks in advance!!

Comment: How about just setting a pref, and ignoring the push if wanted.

Comment: The suggestions about adding a shared pref that keeps track of whether or not the user wants to be notified is fair. However keep in mind that this will only work for FCM data messages. If you send notification messages (like those from the Firebase console) while the app is in the background a notification will be automatically displayed.

Answer (score 1):

you can add some kind of Shared Prefences, and store the value gotten from the user. And then get the value first after getting the notification, if the value of the user is in such case true, then skip the creation of the notification.

Comment: Better view of this is given below!

Comment: Although this sounds like it would work, doesn't this unnecessarily cost battery?

Comment: not at all, although you can also retrieve the user token in a node and with Firebase functions or your server you can search for the token of the user in that node, and if it exists dont send the push notification, is slower and it cost money, that´s why the shared preferences option is the best

Answer (score 1):

You can have a Toggle button for their preferences and then check the value of the toggle before you execute your code. Thus, it becomes as simple as a if-else statement.

```
package com.lfcchile;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

/**
 * Created by Jona on 7/23/16.
 */
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_destacado)
                .setContentTitle("LFC Chile")
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                .setTicker("Ticker")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if(this.isEnabled == true){ // if statement added here
            notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
    }

}
```

This one will work! Make sure the `isEnebled` variable is Global.

Comment: this is not working in my case can you please help me